# users who not buy sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm using oracle sql developer

i have two tables:
users

```
╔══════╤═════════╗
║ u_id │ country ║
╠══════╪═════════╣
║ 11   │ Germany ║
╟──────┼─────────╢
║ 22   │ Germany ║
╟──────┼─────────╢
║ 33   │ Italy   ║
╟──────┼─────────╢
║ 44   │ France  ║
╟──────┼─────────╢
║ 55   │ Spain   ║
╟──────┼─────────╢
║ 66   │ Italy   ║
╟──────┼─────────╢
║ 77   │ Italy   ║
╚══════╧═════════╝
```

and transactions:

```
╔════╤══════╤════════╗
║ id │ u_id │ id_cat ║
╠════╪══════╪════════╣
║ A  │ 11   │ 2      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ B  │ 22   │ 1      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ C  │ 33   │ 2      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ D  │ 33   │ 3      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ E  │ 44   │ 3      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ F  │ 55   │ 2      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ G  │ 66   │ 1      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ H  │ 55   │ 1      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ I  │ 66   │ 1      ║
╟────┼──────┼────────╢
║ J  │ 77   │ 2      ║
╚════╧══════╧════════╝
```

i want to create table with users who lives in (Germany OR Span) AND did NOT buy item from category 1.
so the result should be u_id = 11

i did code:

```
CREATE TABLE    
AS SELECT u.u_id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN transactions s ON u.u_id = s.u_id 
WHERE  
(u.country = 'Germany' OR u.country ='Spain') AND
(s.id_cat != 1)
 ;
```

but it shows u_id = 11 and 55

Comment: The field is `country` in your table and `city` in your SQL Statement. Please **copy and paste** code rather than retyping it, because now we can't be sure if there aren't other typographical errors in your example.

Comment: already fixed, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to use a not exists:

Return all users that are in Germany or Spain; and not those who did not have a ID_CAT 1 transaction.  The coorlated subquery returns all users that have a transaction of 1 and the not exists ensures we only get those users who are not in that list.   This approach generally works well if you need no data from the transactions table; if you need data from the transactions table Gordon's response is preferred.

```
SELECT u.u_id
FROM users u
WHERE u.country IN ('Germany','Spain') 
  and not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM transactions 
                  WHERE T.ID_CAT = 1
                    and t.U_ID = U.U_ID)
```

I follow a general rule of thumb: If I need to select data it should be in the FROM clause.  If I need to limit the data it should be in the where or having.  Some exceptions apply like on outer joins; but it generally gives me a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT u.u_id
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     transactions s
     ON u.u_id = s.u_id 
WHERE  u.city IN ('Germany', 'Spain') 
GROUP BY u.u_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.id_cat = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

This counts the number of transactions with `id_cat = 1`.  And then only returns users where the value is 0.